# Cannot upload data to Dropbox with react-native-blob-util

Tags: javascript, react-native, dropbox-api, react-native-fetch-blob

I am trying to upload a rather large file (~100mb, SQLite database) to Dropbox with `react-native-blob-util`. I authenticate with Dropbox to get an access token `react-native-app-auth`. The response I am getting from `react-native-blob-util` is that it worked: It goes into the `then block`. When I `console.log()` the `res` I get this (the `data` prop looks suspicious):

```
{"array": [Function anonymous], "base64": [Function anonymous], "blob": [Function anonymous], "data": "Error in call to API function \"files/upload\": Invalid authorization value in HTTP header \"Authorization\": \"sl.Bl...\".  Expecting \"Bearer <oauth2-access-token>\".", "flush": [Function anonymous], "info": [Function anonymous], "json": [Function anonymous], "path": [Function anonymous], "readFile": [Function anonymous], "readStream": [Function anonymous], "respInfo": {"headers": {"Accept-Encoding": "identity,gzip", "Cache-Control": "no-cache", "Connection": "close", "Content-Encoding": "gzip", "Content-Security-Policy": "sandbox allow-forms allow-scripts", "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8", "Date": "Sun, 10 Sep 2023 08:21:22 GMT", "Server": "envoy", "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload", "Transfer-Encoding": "Identity", "Vary": "Accept-Encoding", "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff", "X-Dropbox-Request-Id": "0d608050e40b41b79033ad96f82c1fac", "X-Dropbox-Response-Origin": "far_remote", "X-Robots-Tag": "noindex, nofollow, noimageindex"}, "redirects": ["https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload"], "respType": "text", "rnfbEncode": "utf8", "state": "2", "status": 400, "taskId": "...", "timeout": false}, "session": [Function anonymous], "taskId": "xxn9ye010qjh2yjcrl8u8", "text": [Function anonymous], "type": "utf8"}
```

Additionally, there is

a) nothing in my Dropbox  (despite the App-Folder)
b) the upload takes about 1sec which is way too short for ~100mb.

Here is the code.

```
  const _authenticateDropbox = async () => {
    const config = {
      clientId: '...',
      clientSecret: '...',
      redirectUrl: 'org.reactjs.native.example..../oauth',
      scopes: [],
      serviceConfiguration: {
        authorizationEndpoint: 'https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize',
        tokenEndpoint: `https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/token`,
      },
      additionalParameters: {
        token_access_type: 'offline',
      },
    };
    try {
      const user = await authorize(config);
      if (user) {
        if (user.accessToken) _uploadData(user.accessToken);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn('Something went wrong logging in into Dropbox, ', error);
    }
  };

  const _uploadData = accessToken => {
    const dbName = `${DATABASE_NAME}.db`;
    const databasePath = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/${dbName}`;

      ReactNativeBlobUtil.fetch(
        'POST',
        'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload',
        {
          Authorization: accessToken,
          'Dropbox-API-Arg': JSON.stringify({
            path: '/foo.db',
            mode: 'add',
            autorename: true,
            mute: false,
          }),
          'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        },
        ReactNativeBlobUtil.wrap(databasePath),
      )
        .uploadProgress({interval: 250}, (written, total) => {
          ...
        })
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res)
          console.log(accessToken) // its not empty, a looong string starting with sl.BlwH...
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.warn(error) // not logging
        });
  };
```

If I do a

```
const databaseExists = await RNFS.exists(databasePath);
console.log(databaseExists); // true
```

it logs `true`, so the path is correct.
When I check the size of the file (just to make sure that this is no empty file) with

```
ReactNativeBlobUtil.fs
  .stat(databasePath)
  .then(stats => {
    console.log(stats);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.warn(err);
  });
```

It returns

```
{"filename": "foo.db", "lastModified": 1694194258000, "path": "/Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3B433335-5FEA-4324-BCD4-4CBB677C5A4E/data/Containers/Data/Application/98544ECA-3FDF-4D24-AEB8-F1015E2BEEAD/Documents/foo.db", "size": 108924928, "type": "file"}
```

So the file exists and has a size.

What am I missing?

Versions:

```
"react-native": "0.71.7",
"react-native-blob-util": "^0.19.1"
"react-native-app-auth": "^7.0.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

The Authorization header should look like this

```
Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
```